# Error executing child request for

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, global-asax

In my MVC3 application I'm getting the above mention error when I try to handle a maximum request exceeded error.

I'm handling the exception at the application level. I'm trying to redirect to an error page that's located in the Shared folder of the views.

I'm using the code below to redirect to an error page if the request size is over the limit.

```
 this.Server.ClearError();
 this.Server.Transfer("~/Views/Shared/NotAuthorised.cshtml");
```

This is the error im getting.

> *Error executing child request for /SiteName/Views/Shared/NotAuthorised.cshtml*

Comment: There is not enough info here for us to help you. :(

Comment: @gdoron-Please read the updated text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Microsoft documentation ([Error Executing Child Request" Error Message When You Use Server.Transfer or Server.Execute in ASP.NET Page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320439?wa=wsignin1.0)) you cannot use `Server.Transfer` after an application level error.

> Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) dispatches the
>   Server.Transfer or the Server.Execute request to the appropriate
>   Internet Server Application Programming Interface (ISAPI) extension
>   based on the extension of the requesting file. For example, a request
>   for an .aspx page is dispatched to the Aspnet_isapi.dll ISAPI
>   extension.
>
> After the request is dispatched to appropriate ISAPI extension, the
>   ISAPI extension cannot call another ISAPI extension. You receive the
>   error message that is listed in the "Symptoms" section because the
>   Aspnet_isapi.dll file, which handles requests to ASP.NET pages, cannot
>   forward the request to the Asp.dll file, which handles requests to ASP
>   pages.

You can however use `Response.Redirect(path)` like this:

```
Response.Redirect("Home/About");
```

Comment: This worked but here is another way of doing it.

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = "ErrorActionName";

    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
     errorController.Execute(rc);

Comment: I could not upvote your comment enough. This should be a second answer; Response.Redirect was not an option for me, but your solution worked great.

Comment: I have a similar problem explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383468/asp-net-seo-friendly-404-set-redirectmode-in-code Please help

Comment: Doesn't work in 2017... the redirect goes to the correct action, but the page don't move