# asp.net SEO friendly 404 set redirectMode in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I am trying to achive the below configuration through code

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="On" 
         redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">    
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>    
</customErrors>
```

SEO - Handle 404 errors

```
if ((ex is HttpException && 404 == ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode()))
{
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/404.aspx");
    //Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");       
    //Server.Transfer("~/404.aspx"); //Error executing child request for         
}
```

**Question:**
How can I set `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` in programattically here?

I dont want to change the url. 
Calling `Response.Redirect` changes the url to /404.aspx and uses `302 Http Status code`.

I set `Response.StatusCode=404 in page_load` of 404.aspx.

Followed http://weblogs.asp.net/paxer/archive/2010/05/31/asp-net-http-404-and-seo.aspx to implement SEO friendly 404. But via code

Also `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` not at all working

*Server.Transfer* has some errors in Application_Error, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344446/1909604